# Is $1234567891011121314151617181920212223......$ an integer?

Tags: soft-question, definition, integers

This question came from [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459556/the-2013th-digit-of-1234567891011213141516-ldots/459561#459561) and from [that talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Definable_real_number#Berry.27s_paradox.2C_definability_of_definability) where it's noted that "integers have a finite count of digits", so that the "number" in the title is not at all a number (not integer nor rational or real) . This statement seems to me justified because I suspect that if we admit an infinite count of digits we build a set of "numbers" that is not countable (but I've not a proof). I'm wrong?

---

Reading comments and answers I'm a bit confused. So I add a more specific question:
Is the string in the title a number in some model of Peano Axioms?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: $p$-adic integers have infinitely many digits.

Comment: It is not really a number unless you give more context, but rather a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Matt Samuel, which despite the name, aren't integers.

Comment: @Doop right, but they resemble integers that continue off to the left as opposed to the right like a real number.

Comment: Suppose your thing is an integer and call it  $S$. What is $S+1$?

Comment: I modified [the post you referenced](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459556/the-2013th-digit-of-1234567891011213141516-ldots/459561#459561) becuase it is simply wrong to calll $123\ldots$ a number. Your question title is not posed wll, too. I changed your question tile too, because it contains the invalid assumption that this is a number.

Comment: @MattSamuel: For what it's worth, [it's also not $p$-adic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089229/is-123456788910111121314-cdots-a-p-adic-integer?noredirect=1#comment2219322_1089229)

Comment: @miracle Right! thank'you

Comment: What is "some model of integers"? The integers are a specific mathematical object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm thinking to some model of PA. I've corrected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, before we can callthis an integer, we can only call it a *blob of ink* or a *bunch of pixels*. How are some buches of pixels integers and others are not? Well, the *are* not integers, they *represent* integers. For example MMXV, and $2015$, and `0x7DF` are distinct representations of the same integer, and all given with enough "context" to allow us to conclude (more or less easily) what representation scheme was used and that integers "behind" these notations are in fact the same.

I won't go into details of the other two representation, but concentrate on the decimal one. How do we know which number it represents? While the answer seems to be "two thousands and fifteen" obviously, it is not really that obvious.
The *convention*(!) behind the notation is that a *finite* sequence of digit symbols $d_1d_2\ldots d_k$ represents the number $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}10^{i}d_{k-i}$ (with a bit of ignoring the distinction between a digit symbol and its numerical value). Your candidate does not match this convention because it is not a finite sequence. We cannot even read the value of $k$ from it. Admittedly, there are other ways to formulate the convention of deimal representation, but they all fail in some way or other with an infinite digit string (it *may* be appropriate to consider *left*-infinite sequences of digits and view the natural numbers as a subset of the "numbers" obtained this way (by prependingthem with infinitely many zeroes), but beware - the realm of Archimedes-Plutoniumism lurks behind that; and this does not apply to your *right*-infinite string).

To put it differently: Asking what integer an ill-formed (because infinite) sequence of decimal digits represents is not much better than asking what integer the ill-formed "roman numeral" MQLXXRT represents.

Comment: I've accepted the Hagen's answer, but I'm sorry that it's not possible to accept more answers. Many answers and comment have been helpful to better define a new question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115755/possible-not-countable-extension-of-the-natural-numbers

Comment: +1 for Plutoniumism.

Answer (score 8):

This is an *infinite string* of digits. But this string, when we try to interpret it in decimals,  *does not encode a number*, i.e., an element of ${\mathbb N}$ or ${\mathbb R}$. Natural numbers, when written in decimals, appear as *finite strings*, and have a last digit. Noninteger real numbers, when written in decimals, *require a decimal point*, after which an infinity of digits may appear. Therefore, if you decide to insert a decimal point in front or between any two digits in your sequence, you obtain a well defined positive real number.

Answer (score 0):

To say that it is an integer would be to say that it is a natural number, since it is positive. Then, [Peano's $n$th axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) is ill-defined for $ n \ge 6 $, debating the fact that it can even be called a natural number. So I would say no.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on axiomatic, so can you explain me what means "Peano's nth axiom is ill-defined for n≥6"?

Comment: Peano's 6th, 7th, and 8th axioms are ill-defined.

Comment: Why is it ill-defined?

Comment: Because the successor is ill-defined.

Comment: I would not say it is *ill*-defined; obviously, it is undefined in the question, but why is it *ill* defined? I could say it is obtained by incrementing the first digit  checking if there is a carry if so incrementing the next and so on. I think this would actually be a well behaved operation;  it should essentially correspond to arithmetic on the $p$-adic integers, where the string is just written in the sense other than usual. Of course it would not satisfy all axioms but I am not convinced by the argument that the successor is *ill* defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is not an integer. Suppose that you can have an integer with an infinite number of digits. Then by [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument) you can show that the set of all integers in uncountable, which is a contradiction if you accept the Peano axioms as suggested by **Ahaan S. Rungta**. Thus your number cannot be an integer.

Comment: I don't understand what can be a real number with a null decimal expansion that is not an integer.

Comment: There isn't a decimal point in this number. So, while you can't, for example, find the last digit of $\pi$, you should be able to find the "ones" digit, which is what asking for the last digit of this number would be.

Comment: Ahh.. Sorry I was reading the number backwards my misunderstanding. I've edited my answer.

Comment: AFAIK, which is to say not too well, there are models that satisfy the Peano axioms that are in fact not countable.

Comment: @quid: By [Löwenheim-Skolem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Löwenheim–Skolem_theorem), we have that any first-order theory has models of higher cardinality. However, this is not applicable for second-order theories, and indeed [Dedekind showed in 1888](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Models) that there is only one model satisfying the Peano axioms, up to isomorphism.

Comment: @EricStucky thank you for the clarification; it seems I had some confusion among the notions  "Peano arithmetic" and " satisfies Peano axioms."

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more, I quite like that argument.

Comment: @EricStucky If I well understand: the string in title is non a number in second-order theory, but is a number in some first order theory?

Comment: @EmilioNovati: That's possible, perhaps in some nonstandard model of Robinson arithmetic. But, it's still not terribly clear what your string is "supposed to" represent. For instance (with thanks to KCd), $123456789101112\cdots$ is "supposed to" represent
$$1+20+300+4⋅104+\cdots+9⋅109+0⋅1010+1⋅1011+\cdots,$$
which despite not being a number in the usual sense is still an object that is intuitively plausible.

Comment: Perhaps we could formalize it by inventing a notion of "dual numbers" which are like numbers but flipped around. But even doing something we'd like to be simple [like adding two dual numbers] becomes theoretically difficult, if it is even possible. Never mind the difficulties in trying to add a number and a dual number, which seems like something we'd want to do if our number system included both.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same thing as asking whether infinity an integer. But integer MUST have a finite number of digits. (the number in that title is "BOGUS")